# Can I embed Plotly-generated html file in README.md of my Github repository?

Tags: html, github, plotly, markdown, readme

I just output an interactive 3D plot from **Plotly** as html file, and I saw blogs about embedding it in webspages and RMarkdown files, which got me wondering: Is it possible to embed it in a **Markdown** file? In particular, can I embed the html in the **README.md** of my Github repository? Should be cool.

Comment: Does the HTML file use colors, CSS, or JavaScript?

Comment: @bk2204 Ah.... I have no idea... but Plotly is written in JavaScript, so I think the html is as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML is simple HTML without any colors, font tags, CSS, or JavaScript, then yes, you can embed it, and it will probably work.  However, for security, functionality, and accessibility reasons, GitHub filters out most colors, font tags, CSS, and JavaScript from the HTML that's rendered, no matter how it comes in.

So if your Plotly-generated HTML uses those features, then it won't work.  You could embed it as an image if that's suitable for your needs.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much! What about markdown file in general?

Comment: You can probably embed a subset of it (like an appropriate `div` tag) in markdown in general.

Comment: Depending on how you embed it and the Markdown processor in general.  Markdown is designed for writing documents, so embedding interactive items is not considered a primary use case.  You can certainly try it, but you may be better off writing a simple HTML document.